# Installing Microsoft Z3 Theorem Prover on a Macbook M1

Tags: macos, installation, z3, apple-m1

I recently changed my old macbook air and purchased a macbook M1. I would like to install on it [Microsoft Research Z3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/z3-3/).

> Is it possible? Does it work on M1?

I went to github [link](https://github.com/z3prover/z3) where there is everything one needs to install z3. Unfortunately I have to admit that I am not IT savvy at all, *and going to that link I don't even know where to begin.*

**Q.**

> Is there anyone so kind to explain to me how to install z3 in little steps like I am really dumb and know very little about IT technical stuff?

Thanks for your kind help. Feel free to edit the tags as you see appropriate.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions under `Building Z3 using make and GCC/Clang` in the page you linked? Did it fail for some reason?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have to admit that I do not know what GCC/Clang is, and I do not know what I have to download before following the instructions, let alone how to follow the instructions. If someone could translate those instructions in a "for dummies" manner that would be great.

Comment: I'm afraid stack-overflow isn't a good forum for this sort of question; as it isn't really about z3. You might want to try https://superuser.com instead.

Comment: Thank you.. I posted here cause I saw other questions on how to install z3 here and more broadly about z3. I believe here there might be people who could help me more readily than on the other forum, where they probably don't even know what z3 is..

Answer (score 0):

Actually I already spent 2 days with this. So I decide to use VM Ubuntu. I suggest VM who are using M1-M2 Macbook. Right now everything is working for me.

Install z3 by entering the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install z3
```

And if will you get LLVM error : https://apt.llvm.org/

But if you want to continue with M1 firstly run

```
brew install z3
```

and also add these in stack.yaml

```
extra-include-dirs:
- /opt/homebrew/opt/23/include
extra-lib-dirs:
- /opt/homebrew/opt/z3/lib
```